# How to convert a timezone in logs as they are being tailed

Tags: sed, awk, logs, tail

I would like to manipulate the format of a datestamp from a log, in realtime, as it is being tailed. The current format is `2016-04-06T23:19:20.878Z`. I would like to convert it to our local timezone and potentially remove the milliseconds. Can I pipe the output of `tail -f` into something like `awk` or `sed` so that this can be done in realtime with the remainder of the output unchanged?

Answer (score 2):

If you know which field the timestamp is in, eg the 2nd word, you can use awk to do the conversion by getting it to call `date`:

```
stdbuf -oL tail -f ... |
awk -v timefield=2 '{
  if($timefield ~ /[0-9].*Z/){
    "date --date \"" $timefield "\"" | getline tod
     sub($timefield,tod,$0)
  }
  print 
}'
```

You may need to get tail to not buffer to the pipe, as shown above with `stdbuf -oL`.
If you don't know the field, or if it moves, you can try to match the timezone pattern on each word:

```
awk  '{
  for(timefield = 1;timefield<=NF;timefield++)
    if($timefield ~ /^[0-9].*T.*Z$/){
      "date --date \"" $timefield "\"" | getline tod
      sub($timefield,tod,$0)
    }
   print 
}'
```

This assumes your timestamp is separated by whitespace.

---

Using your example in the comments of `I2016-04-08T00:34:29.372Z]v3087`, you can extract the timestamp by using awk's `substr(string,offset,length)`, as it has a constant length and offset: `datestamp = substr($timefield, 2, 24)`. If you dont want to preserve the initial `I` and trailing code in the resulting output, you end up with:

```
awk -v timefield=1 '{
  if($timefield ~ /[0-9].*Z/){
     datestamp = substr($timefield, 2, 24)
    "date --date \"" datestamp "\"" | getline tod
     sub($timefield,tod,$0)
  }
  print 
}'
```

If you want to keep the extra code, change the `sub` to replace the datestamp string rather than the entire field, eg with extra spaces: `sub(datestamp," " tod " ",$0)`.

Comment: If fields are delimited by whitespace than the actual first word is `I2016-04-08T00:34:29.372Z]v3087` where the first letter can be I or E for Info or Error. How do I do matchgroups within timefield to pull out just timestamp and ignore the I or E and the trailing version number?

Comment: @emkman I updated my answer with a possible solution.